# Aviso de Errors no console

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-3

Os seguintes avisos estão aparecendo no console com chrome:

"Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function        bootstrap.js:29"

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token [                angular.js:12330"

Segue meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="fluxo">
<head>
<title>Fluxojoin</title>
<meta charset="utf8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fj.css">

<script>
angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/entradas", {
        templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
        controller: "fluxoCtrl"
});
$routeProvider.when("/saidas", {
    templateUrl: "views/saidas.html",
    controller: "fluxoCtrl"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});
});

angular.module("fluxo").controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

var mostraTodasContasEntradas = function () {
    $http.get("php/index.php").success(function (data){

    });
}

mostraTodasContasEntradas();

});
</script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="fluxoCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'views/links.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Referente ao `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function bootstrap.js:29` você tem que importar o jQuery também.

Comment: Acredito que não seja necessário @devgaspa, pois o $routeProvider não exige uma definição dele para cada caso, então ele não espera que exista um `$` e sim um código nativo do angularJs, ou no caso dele, uma nova condição de `.when`. Pelo menos pela estrutura atual, acredito que seja esse o problema

Comment: @CelsomTrindade mas o `TypeError` esta acontecendo dentro do bootstrap.js

Comment: Mas provavelmente seja isso. Como o bootstrap trabalha mais em conjunto com jquery, ele deve esperar uma função em jquery. Mas ele não possui nenhuma função que seja voltada a isso. Deve ser apenas um "mal entendido" entre os códigos. Pois ele chamou o bootstrap.js mas atualmente não faz nenhuma função referente à ele. Pelo menos não no exemplo disponibilizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu `$routeProvider` está definido de modo errado, você só precisa de uma definição dele, e não uma para cada `.when`.

Tente o seguinte:

```
$routeProvider
.when("/entradas", {
    templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
    controller: "fluxoCtrl"
})
.when("/saidas", {
    templateUrl: "views/saidas.html",
    controller: "fluxoCtrl"
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});
```

### Edit:

Na verdade, lendo a documentação do bootstrap, notei que realmente falta o Jquery ser iniciado, conforme o @devgaspar disse.

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).
>
> Note que que todos os plugins dependem do jQuery (significa que o jQuery deve ser iniciado antes do bootstrap).

Então minha solução anterior não resolve o seu problema do primeiro erro de console, mas fica como indicação de melhoria no código.

Comment: Celsom, tenho outro exemplo que está com o $routeProvider assim como fiz e funciona, não aparece nenhum aviso.

Comment: Não, não tem inicialização do bootstrap.js.
E todo o meu $routeProvider está em um arquivo separado.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu, mas agora deu outro erro, pois não aparece nada na tela.
E isso está aparecendo no console:
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=fluxo&p1=ReferenceE…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A464)"

Comment: Tirei os ";" que tinham no final de cada um tb, como você fez e melhorou.
Mas ainda tenho os mesmos avisos no console.

Comment: Tirei o bootstrap.js e agora está tudo OK.

Comment: Mas pq preciso do JQuery pra usar o bootstrap?

Comment: Você precisa do jQuery se for usar algum plugin JS nativo do próprio bootstrap, por exemplo: o carousel, accordion, ou outros plugins que eles tenham. Se for utilizar só o `css` para usar o grid deles, estilo de botões, etc.. Não precisa dos arquivos JS. Entendeu?

Comment: Sim... Tirei mesmo ele. Deixar só com os css

Comment: Celsom, você entende de AngularJS?

Comment: Olha.. eu tenho trabalhado exclusivamente com AngularJs já faz alguns meses, apesar de ter aprendido tudo sozinho. Mas conheço bastante coisa sim. Migrei de jQuery para AngularJs.

Comment: Show... Iniciei com o Angular a 1 mês atrás.
Te pergunto isso pelo seguinte. Tentei colocar o arquivo de config, de rotas em um outro arquivo e chamar ele no index.html, como já vi em uma vídeo aula:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fluxoConfig.js"></script>

E já fiz isso e funcionou... Mas agora ta loqueado, quando rodo parece que ele não está reconhecendo a importação, a chamada do arquivo acima!

Comment: Você consegue fornecer o exemplo mais completo? Com o código todo para eu ver?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31362/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-gustavosevero).